# match pandas DataFrame rows with dict of key/value pairs

Tags: python, pandas, profiling

I am looking to do the following:

```
df.loc[(df["first_name"] == "joko") & (df["last_name"] == "widodo"), "are_you_joko"]
```

but, without explicitly providing the column names and values in the line **(df["first_name"] == "joko") & (df["last_name"] == "widodo")**.  rather, i'd like to provide a dict of key/value pairs, such as, **{"first_name": "joko", "last_name": "widodo"}**.  also, i'd like to accomplish this in the fastest way possible.  i am currently using the following.

```
tf_df = pd.DataFrame([df[k] == v for k, v in record_dict.iteritems()]).all()
df.loc[:, "are_you_joko"] = tf_df
```

where **record_dict** is **{"first_name": "joko", "last_name": "widodo"}**.  I am interested if somebody knows of anything much faster.  thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that creating a new `DataFrame` may take time & memory if your df is large. I tried something like this and it's 500+ times faster than yours on my machine when `len(df) = 100000`. If your `df` is small, I guess there is no difference.

```
In [1]:

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
​
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(3, size=(100000,5)), columns=list('ABCDE'))
​
record_dict = dict(A=1, B=2, C=1, D=2, E=1)
In [2]:

%%timeit 
tf_df = pd.DataFrame([df[k] == v for k, v in record_dict.iteritems()]).all()
1 loops, best of 3: 2.34 s per loop
In [3]:

%%timeit
msk = None
for k, v in record_dict.iteritems():
    if msk is None:
        msk = df[k] == v
    else:
        msk = msk & (df[k] == v)       
100 loops, best of 3: 4.14 ms per loop
```